# How to migrate tables in order in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration

I am having a problem migrating my tables because there are relations between them.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_portal_development_items`.`budgets` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `budgets` add constraint `budgets_budget_type_id_foreign` foreign key (`budget_type_id`) references `budget_types` (`id`))
```

when the budget table is migrating there is a foreign key of budget_type_id and that budget_type_id is the primary key in the budget_types table

if the budget table is migrating, it needs budget_type migrated. but I created budget_type later hence throwing an error.

If I rename the migration files will it cause any problem?

I typed

```
php artisan migrate
```

and it throws an error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `laravel_portal_development_items`.`budgets` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `budgets` add constraint `budgets_budget_type_id_foreign` foreign key (`budget_type_id`) references `budget_types` (`id`))
```

Comment: edit their filenames => the order of timestamp part

Comment: Will they cause any problems later?

Comment: `2014_10_12_200000_create_budget_types_table.php` `2014_10_12_200001_create_budgets_table.php`. No the name of the files causes no problems

Comment: You can put the foreign key relationships in their own migration that runs after the other tables are created.